# How can you derive confidence intervals for a bent cable model?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, nonlinear-regression

Using the function bent.cable in the SiZer package in R, one can fit a "bent cable model" in R.

Here is an example of how I used it and the plot it made.

```
model.bc.mean=bent.cable(flow.new.sum.dat$l2Flow,flow.new.sum.dat$TCTmean,grid.size =200)

x.grid <- seq(min(flow.new.sum.dat$TCTmean), max(flow.new.sum.dat$TCTmean), length=77)
```

x.grid looks like 0.00100 , 0.2485, 0.4961,...., 18.56, 18.816

```
plot(flow.new.sum.dat$l2Flow,flow.new.sum.dat$TCTmean)
lines(x.grid, predict(model.bc.mean, x.grid), col='red')
```

it looks like this:[image]

The question I have now is how to derive confidence bounds for this model.
Using the standard predict function does not work, nor does using predict.nls. Basically I want to derive confidence intervals for the above regression line.
Any ideas/packages/suggestions? Thanks

Comment: FWIW, the lack of fit is so clear and large that confidence intervals aren't worth much. This model appears to employ at least four parameters; with that many parameters you can achieve a much better fit with other models.  What is the reason for choosing this one?

Comment: The reason is that there should be a "limit of detection" whereby after a certain x-value we obtain y values of 0 or near 0. As it relates to a biological process.

Comment: That's a reason to select an appropriate model, but it's not a reason to select *this* one.  The scientific theory of this biological process will provide the best guide to selecting a model or family of models to fit to the data.